# What are rate (request) limits for https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

Tags: api, gmail, rate-limiting

I have an app that 2 times in 1 second, checks the url:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom`

after around 10 minutes we get error `The remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized`.

It's generally caused by incorrect credentials, but as this is not case with us (just happens 10 minutes after working of app), i doubt it might be about limits. In G-Docs, i nowhere could find if there are any limits for that api. How/where I can find the limits for that endpoint?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  and the full error message.  Rate limits are normally flood protection your going to fast.

Comment: @dalmTo, I am not sure about your comment. firstly, code here is totally irrelevant, as the response is from pure curl request of that url.  (can it be in : javascript, php, c#, python or whatever), and second, i've posted full error message caught by exception. So, everything needed was included.

Comment: Unauthorized means that you are not properly authenticating your call. Without seeing your code in (Javascript, php, c#, python or whatever) how would you like me to describe to you how to properly authenticate a call. You also haven't mentioned if you are using Oauth2, a service account, or api key to authenticate your cal. Without additional information (Your code) how can i help?   You have enough points to know this **The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**